# Is there any way to highlight one particular series in highcharts?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I'm rendering a multiple series line chart using highcharts in my component. I have a requirement on this chart, When we hover on any series only that particular series has to be highlighted.

I have 5 lines series, say l1-l5. If I hover on l2, only l2 should have opacity 1, all other lines should have opacity 0.5. Check below screenshot

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My proposition change the tooltip color and the line color too. I used the tooltip option `shared:true` to gather all serie and then the events on each serie for the correct color.

```
let color = null,
colorIndex = null,
colors = ['rgba(200,150,168,0.5)', 'rgba(120,250,60,0.5)',
          'rgba(40,250,208,0.5)', 'rgba(90,10,208,0.5)'];

plotOptions: {
  series: {
    events: {
      mouseOver: function() {
        color = (colors[this.index]).replace('0.5', '1');
        colorIndex = this.index;
        this.chart.series[this.index].update({
          color: color
        });
      },
      mouseOut: function() {
        this.chart.series[this.index].update({
          color: colors[this.index]
        });
      }
    }
  }
},
tooltip: {
  useHTML:true,
  formatter: function() {
    s = '<b>' + this.points[0].key + '</b><br/>';

    this.points.forEach(function(point, index) {
      if (index !== colorIndex){
          s += '<span style="color:' + point.color 
            + ';margin-right:2px">\u25CF</span> <span style="color: #c6c6c6">' 
            + point.series.name 
            + ': <b>' + point.y + ' '  + '</b><br>';
       } else{
          s += '<span style="color:' + point.color 
            + ';margin-right:2px">\u25CF</span> <span style="color: #000">' 
            + point.series.name 
            + ': <b>' + point.y + ' '  + '</b><br>';
       }
    });
    return s;
  },
  shared: true
}
```

[API - mouseOver / mouseOut](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.line.events.mouseOut)

[API - tooltip formatter](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/tooltip.formatter)

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/core972/6dmepnz8/)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the default tooltip behavior with `formatter` function to include all current series points:

```
tooltip: {
    formatter: function() {
        var series = this.series.chart.series,
            resultStr = '<span style="color:' + this.point.color + '">\u25CF</span> ' + this.series.name + ': <b>' + this.point.y + '</b><br/>';

        series.forEach(function(s) {
            if (s !== this.series) {
                resultStr += '<span style="color:' + s.points[this.point.index].color + '">\u25CF</span><span style="color: #c6c6c6"> ' + s.name + ': ' + s.points[this.point.index].y + '</span><br/>';
            }
        }, this);

        return resultStr;
    }
}
```

Live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/yxmne0s6/

API: https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/tooltip.formatter